# The new state serializer must not be incompatible with the old state serializer in Apche Flink SQL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am reading data from Flink Datastream using Kafka (reading from multiple streams), then i am converting those streams in to temporary View using flink SQL and perform join operations. For join operations also, i am using Flink SQL. The problem I am facing is when i am adding new field in flink sql query, and then trying to migrate savepoint, I am having this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.StateMigrationException: The new state serializer (org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.MapSerializer@58eac6c9) must not be incompatible with the old state serializer (org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.MapSerializer@a56de33a).
```

Note: When I checked, this error is coming when i changed the query and not the pojo of the datastream.

Comment: What does your classpath look like?  Any chance that you have multiple copies of the class MapSerializer on it? 

I'm wondering if two different versions have been loaded and that's what is causing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for query evolution in Flink SQL, as highlighted in the documentation https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/upgrading/#table-api--sql

A change in your SQL query means that you'll have to restart without a savepoint.